# Routing for optionally logged-in users in sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, backend, laravel-sanctum

Sanctum shared middleware Auth:sanctum and it works. Look at this code:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/profile', [TestController::class, 'test']);
});
```

And controller's method

```
public function test()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return 'user';
    } else {
        return 'Guest';
    }
}
```

Problem is that if my routing use `auth:santum` everything work's for logged users but for guest I have unauthorized. If don't use this middleware, Auth does't work correctly and don't see that iI'm logged-in (always return 'Guest'). How can I solve my problem? I want to display user if I'm lodded, else I need to display Guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is authenticated with Sanctum try using : `auth('sanctum')->check()`